# Blocking YouTube video playback from specific links on iPads managed by Apple's MDM

Tags: youtube-api, iso, mdm, mobile-devices, webfiltering

I'm an IT administrator at a middle school, and I've been tasked with preventing the playback of YouTube videos on our school iPads. While I noticed that some pages contain links to https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api, I don't want to block pages that contain this link. Instead, I want to block the actual playback of YouTube videos when these specific links are clicked.

Is there a way to achieve this using Apple's MDM?

Here's what I've considered:

- Web Filtering: While I can easily block domains like youtube.com, blocking specific URLs like youtube.com/iframe_api seems more challenging.
- Custom Profiles: I'm aware that MDM allows for pushing custom profiles to devices. Can I leverage this to restrict specific JavaScript functions?
- On-premises Web Proxy: If devices connect to the internet through the company's network, utilise an on-premises web proxy to consistently modify or introduce CSP headers.
- Third-party Solutions: I'm open to suggestions for third-party content filtering solutions that might address this issue.

Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!